# Error when executing ContentResolver insert

Tags: android

Got errors when executing insert new data into content provider,see below code, PS.I just put below codes directly into onCreate() of Activity,then execute.

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,"Example Song");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,"Unknown");

getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values);
```

just simply insert new song data, but got below error occurs.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1605)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1254)
at com.example.flover.contentproviderdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
```

Could anyone tell me why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify the line number 48 from your Main Activity. The error is in that line, as mentioned in your stack trace.

Comment: Line 48 is getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values), thanks for replying

Comment: i am -almost- sure that `lastIndexOf()` is called on the `ContentProvider` class and it uses the `URI` parameter to find out which data/id/... is related to the request, but what i can't explain, why it would be null? i mean the `URI` is null? the passed value is `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` this is API constant?! how it could be null?

Comment: Firstly thanks for ur reply, I guess the problem would be the uri which is MediaStore. Audio. Media. EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, but that uri is only one I found to insert. So if this way is troubled, how to insert music info such as title, artist into content provider?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: @Fllo here is solution for my question,[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588495/manual-add-song-to-mediastore-as-a-music-track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588495/manual-add-song-to-mediastore-as-a-music-track), adding new song to android provider, you have to retrieve all the metadata and add needed info to provider database, otherwise song will be not showed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was getting the same error pre android Q (API 29)

If you are downloading a file to the media store PRE Android Q (Api 29) include in your content values...

```
    val directory = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)

    contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, "${directory}${song?.title}")
```

Api 29 and onwards omit the DATA value.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much. For my own understanding, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: its working but, this way is no where mention in  Add an item __https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item__