# Saving files to MediaStore on devices running Android below 10

Tags: android, audio, download, mime-types, mediastore

I am writing code for downloading and storing in MediaStore files of different types. For devices running Android 10 and above I store all of them to `Downloads` collection, and it works fine. Those running Android below 10 don't have this collection. At the beginning I tried to store them to the `Files` collection, but it turned out that it's not possible to store for example image to the `Files` collection. So I came to this code:

```
fun createDownloadsFile(context: Context, fileName: String, mimeType: String): Uri? {
    val values = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
    }
    val collection = if (hasAndroid10()) {
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_PENDING, 1)
        MediaStore.Downloads.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    } else getMediaStoreCollectionBelowAndroid10(mimeType)

    return context.contentResolver.insert(collection, values)
}

private fun getMediaStoreCollectionBelowAndroid10(mimeType: String): Uri = when {
    mimeType.startsWith("image/") -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    mimeType.startsWith("audio/") -> MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    mimeType.startsWith("video/") -> MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    else -> MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
}
```

Images and videos now get stored fine on Android below 10. But attempts to store audio crash on the line `contentResolver.insert(collection, values)` with:
*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)' on a null object reference*

Attempts to store files of type different from image, video and audio crash on the same row with:
*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no path was provided when inserting new file*

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Use the .DATA column to indicate where the file should be stored. But for below Android 10 it makes no sense to use the media store.

Comment: @blackapps use .DATA like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496366/3400881 for audio/* mimeType and all mimeTypes excepto of image/* and video/* ?

Comment: You cannot use the media store for external files dir. That is an app specific directory where the media store keeps its hands off.

Comment: Could you show or link some code sample demonstrating your solution?

Comment: @blackapps "But for below Android 10 it makes no sense to use the media store" - I need these files to be opened with other apps. As I understand If my app targets API level 30, than other apps won't be able to access `file://` Uri even though device is running Android below 10. Right?

Comment: You can use, no you have to use,  FileProvider to serve your files to other apps with ACTION_VIEW.

Comment: Any solid solution for this issue?

Comment: @blackapps why you not try in detail solution, related to media store. as I saw you have commented my question related to this topic.